# Accessing values and comparing them with read.table in R

Tags: r, file-io, read.table

I read in a large tab separated file as follows:

```
file <- read.table(file.choose(), header=FALSE, sep='\t', fill=TRUE)
colnames(file) <- c("a","b","c","d")
```

I know that this part works, but then I use the following code to access the data in the file:

```
for(i in file){
  if(i==1){
    nums <- c(nums, file$d[i])
    name <- file$b[i]
  }else if(file$b[i] == file$b[i-1]){
    nums <- c(nums, file$d[i])
  }else if(file$b[i] != file$b[i-1]){
    txt <- c(txt, file$b[i-1] + function(nums,10,1))
    nums <- file$d
    name <- file$b[i]
  }
}

writeLines(txt, "results.txt")
```

function returns a changed nums, and 2 other numbers.  I know the function works because I tested it on a smaller dataset that I wrote in myself, but now I need to test by reading in the large file that has multiple parts.  When I run the program, I receive the following error:

> Error in if (file$b[i] == file$b[i - 1]) { :     missing value where
>   TRUE/FALSE needed  In addition: Warning messages:
>
> 1: In if (i == 1) { :the condition has length > 1 and only the first
>   element will be used
>
> 2: In Ops.factor(i, 1) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
>
> 3: In if(file$b[i] == file$b[i - 1]) { :   the condition has length >
>   1 and only the first element will be used writeLines(txt,
>   "results.txt")
>
> Error in writeLines(txt, "results.txt") : invalid 'text' argument

Comment: Can you provide some test data? Also, for now, try changing `for(i in file)` to `for(i in 1:nrow(file))`.

Comment: Most likely @YannisVassiliadis has correctly pointed out the problem in your code. In case you still get error then please refer `file$b[i] == file$b[i-1]` condition. Any `NA` values with equality check (`==`)  results in error. Then you will have 2 choices. Remove `NAs` from the data or check for `is.na` before equality condition.